# How to change Laravel's Job Batching table name and connection

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, job-batching

Laravel 8 introduced [Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-batching), which allows to execute jobs in batches and perform actions on batch completion. However Laravel documentation does not have a section regarding configurations of Job Batching table and database connection.

How can different database for `job_batching` table can be specified, and is it possible to rename the `job_batching` table name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `queue.php` file in the `config/` folder.

You can specify custom database and table name by editing/adding the `batching` key:

```
return [
    /* Default Queue Connection Name */
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),
    ...

    // ADD THIS SECTION
    'batching' => [
        'database' => '<custom_database>',
        'table' => '<custom_job_batching>',
    ],

    ...
];
```